# Bad performance for muli joined sub-queries

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Could someone help me on this query. When generating the related report through web application it times out due to response time taking over 30seconds(standard http request time out).

```
select   c.counterparty_shortname                                                       AS  [Réference]
        ,cty.counterparty_type_name                                                     AS  [Type ref]
        ,t.transaction_shortname                                                        AS  [transaction_shortname]
        ,mitigant_shortname
        ,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(tce.outstanding_amount,0)),0) 
          from  transaction_credit_event tce
         where tce.transaction_id=t.transaction_id)                                     AS  [Montant impayé]
         ,(select count(t1.transaction_id)
        from [transaction] t1
        where t1.counterparty_id=c.counterparty_id)                                     AS  [Nbre affaire]
        ,(select  isnull(count(tce.credit_event_id),0)
        from transaction_credit_event tce 
        where tce.transaction_id=t.transaction_id  
        and isnull(tce.outstanding_amount,0)>0
        and tce.credit_event_type_id=51)                                                AS  [nbr impaye]
        ,TT.transaction_type_name                                                       AS  [Type Produit]
        ,isnull(cm1.value1_text,'')                                                     AS  [type garantie] 
        ,isnull(cm2.value1_text,'')                                                     AS [marque] 
        ,isnull(cm3.value1_text,'')                                                     AS [modele] 
        ,(select top 1 tmp1.payment_posting_date 
         from (select  pp.payment_posting_date                      
                      ,tce.transaction_id                                       
               FROM    payment_posting  pp
               inner JOIN transaction_credit_event tce 
               ON pp.credit_event_id=tce.credit_event_id) tmp1
         where tmp1.transaction_id=t.transaction_id
         order by tmp1.payment_posting_date desc)                                       AS [Date dernier paiement]
        ,fate_shortname                                                                 AS [sort]
        ,raf.recovery_action_fate_id
        ,ISNULL(t.outstanding_amount,0)                                                 AS [CRD]
        ,1                                                                              AS [ID]
        ,(select  isnull(count(tce.credit_event_id),0)
        from transaction_credit_event tce,[transaction] tt 
        where tce.transaction_id=tt.transaction_id 
        and  tt.counterparty_id=c.counterparty_id
        and isnull(tce.outstanding_amount,0)>0
        and tce.credit_event_type_id=51)                                                AS  [nbr impaye tiers]
        ,convert(date,dispatch_start_date,103)                                          AS [date debut]
        ,convert(date,dispatch_end_date,103)                                            AS [date fin]
        ,c.counterparty_type_id
        ,t.transaction_type_id


from counterparty c
inner join wf_task_dispatch w       on w.item_id=c.counterparty_id
inner join [transaction] t          on c.counterparty_id=t.counterparty_id
LEFT join transaction_recovery tr   on tr.counterparty_id=c.counterparty_id and tr.transaction_recovery_id=(select top 1 transaction_recovery_id from transaction_recovery where counterparty_id=c.counterparty_id order by idate desc)
LEFT join recovery_action_fate raf  on raf.recovery_action_fate_id=tr.recovery_action_fate_id
left join counterparty_type cty     on cty.counterparty_type_id=c.counterparty_type_id
left join [transaction_type] TT     on t.transaction_type_id = TT.transaction_type_id
inner join mitigant_transaction mt  on mt.transaction_id=t.transaction_id and mt.ddate is null
inner join mitigant m               on m.mitigant_id=mt.mitigant_id and mitigant_screen='asset' and m.ddate is null
left join constant_matrix cm1       on cm1.criteria1_text=m.regulatory_mitigant_type and cm1.constant_matrix_shortname='CAIN'  and cm1.ddate is null
left join constant_matrix cm2       on cm2.criteria1_text=m.valuation_frequency and cm2.constant_matrix_shortname='MARQ'  and cm2.ddate is null
left join constant_matrix cm3       on cm3.criteria1_text=m.valuation_source and cm3.constant_matrix_shortname='GMOD'  and cm3.ddate is null
```

where (select [dbo].FN_GetPhase)=81

Comment: Look at the execution plan, and provide indexes wherever they are missing.

Comment: Sorry I haven't possibility to change anything on table. Just read only.

Comment: Could someone help please.

Comment: How long does it take to execute using SSMS?
Does the execution plan indicate which part of the query is taking the most time?
Can you take the sub queries out the select and put them into the FROM section and join to those tables?